# htop : swapping when still having freememory

Tags: htop

I am using htop and I don't understand this output (MAC OS 10.13): 
[image]

I understand there is 748 M of swap, while 4.7g of memory is free.. Why is there swap when there is free memory ? Do I miss something ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions. Perhaps you should try one of our sister sites [apple.se], [su], or [unix.se] for this particular topic. (But check their respective help sections before posting; this is a suggestion to find out if they would be more suitable, not a suggestion to simply copy/paste this to another site.)

Comment: thanks... I shamefuly copy-pasted :-/ https://superuser.com/questions/1284555/htop-swapping-when-still-having-freememory